Extract Blob Contents into another table in oracle sql
I am having a table with schema
create table file_ingestion_table 
(File_id    NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 14486912 CACHE 1000 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE ,
FileName    varchar2(1000),
FileType    varchar2(16),
FileContent Blob,
tag varchar2(64),
Who varchar2(100),
Status varchar2(64))
;

this table contents file loaded by end users in column fileContent (This will always contain either csv,json, no other objects are allowed), I want to read this blob file content and insert the values(file contents) into the destination table.
For example - I have uploaded a file with columns Name,Department, Salary then I want to read this blob and insert the data for all the rows into the destination employee table with columns - Name,Department, Salary.

A BLOB is binary data - it could be an image, or a PDF or a text file or an executable; we just don't know what it could contain and any one of those different formats would require a different way of extracting the data. No-one can tell you how to extract data from something where we do not know its structure. Please [edit] the question and include a specification for how the BLOB data is formatted and your attempt at trying to read the data. Otherwise the question is not answerable.

As mentioned in the comment BLOB is binary data and could hold different formats. You say that only csv and json are alowed. It would be wise to consider CLOB datatype. Anyway, to get the data out of it you should know data format and structure. It is impossible to give an explicite general answer, so I will try to give a simple json example of fetching json data from BLOB column:
--  S a m p l e    T a b l e :
create table blob_file_table 
(File_id    NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 14486912 CACHE 1000 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE ,
FileName    varchar2(1000),
FileType    varchar2(16),
FileContent Blob,
tag varchar2(64),
Who varchar2(100),
Status varchar2(64));

Insert Into blob_file_table 
(FileName, FileType, FileContent, tag, Who, Status)
VALUES
('File1', 'json', JSON_SERIALIZE ('{"name":"John", "department":30, "salary":8500}' RETURNING BLOB), 'tag', 'who', 'ok')

--     S a m p l e    D a t a :
Select * From blob_file_table;

--  FILE_ID    FILENAME    FILETYPE    FILECONTENT                                      TAG    WHO     STATUS
-- --------    ---------   ---------   -----------------------------------------------  -----  -----   ---------
-- 14486912    File1       json        {"name":"John","department":30,"salary":8500}    tag    who     ok         */

... getting json BLOB data as sql query columns using JSON_TABLE() ...
--      S Q L :
Select  b.FileName, b.FileType, j.*
From    blob_file_table b,
        JSON_TABLE(FileContent, '$'
                   Columns ( NAME       VarChar2(32) PATH '$.name',
                             DEPARTMENT Number(3)    PATH '$.department',
                             SALARY     Number(14,2) PATH '$.salary')
                  ) j

/*      R e s u l t :
FILENAME    FILETYPE    NAME       DEPARTMENT      SALARY
---------   ---------   -------   -----------   ---------
File1       json        John               30        8500     */

See the fiddle here.
Note: This query could be used to update another table either directly or using MERGE INTO ...
